# Error processing method: 'System.Void NLog.LogReceiverService.NLogEvent

Tags: xamarin.forms, sdk

I have a .NET standard Xamarin Forms application developing in Visual Studio 2017. I am facing an error while building in Release mode by linking SDK assemblies only.

I tried with a custom linker file with NLog assembly but it was failed. Please see the detailed error below.

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error       The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
    Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void NLog.LogReceiverService.NLogEvent::set_Values(System.String)' in assembly: 'NLog.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.String[] System.String::Split(System.Char,System.StringSplitOptions)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
       at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
       at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
       at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
       at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() bpost.mobile.mytransport.Droid
```

The application works perfect in Debug mode and in Release mode without linking. But the apk size is about 80 MB!

Comment: Can you please try to update your Visual-Studio to the latest version and try again?

Comment: Thanks. It worked in VS2017 15.9 version!